# Unterschied zwischen „verwehren“ und „verweigern“

Tags: difference

Ich habe den Eindruck, dass es kaum einen Unterschied zwischen diesen Wörtern gibt:

> jemandem den Zutritt verweigern
>
> jemandem den Zutritt verwehren
>
> ein Gläschen in Ehren kann niemand verwehren
>
> ein Gläschen in Ehren kann niemand verweigern

Beim Reden zögere ich ein wenig, wenn ich eines von diesen Wörtern wählen muss. Gibt es überhaupt einen Unterschied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Gibt es überhaupt einen Unterschied?

Es gibt kaum einen Unterschied aber einen kleinen.

*Verweigern* kann implizieren, dass eine Person aktiv etwas nicht zulassen will, während *Verwehren* allgemeiner verwendet werden kann (z.B. *per jure*).

Zum Beispiel

> > Ich (Person) *verweigere* die Aussage (in einem Verhör)

vs.

> > Der Zutritt zu militärischem Sperrgebiet ist unbefugten Personen *verwehrt* (per jure).

Answer (score 4):

Die Bedeutung ist sehr ähnlich und in den meisten Fällen können die Wörter als synonym betrachtet werden.

Allerdings gibt es auch Fälle, in denen nur eines der Wörter passt. Das ist beispielsweise so, wenn *verweigern* als Synonym für *sich weigern* benutzt wird. Beispiele:

> Ich verweigere, das zu tun.

D.h. der Sprecher weigert sich, das zu tun. "Ich verwehre, das zu tun" bedeutet dagegen, dass der Sprecher jemanden etwas verbietet. Ähnlich gelagert ist

> Sie verweigert sich dieser Zumutung.

D.h. sie weist die Zumutung zurück. Letztes Beispiel:

> Das Pferd verweigerte den Sprung über das Hindernis.

Und hier noch das Sprichwort aus der Frage:

> Ein Gläschen in Ehren kann niemand verwehren.

Einmal davon abgesehen, dass es ich um einen Reim handelt, bedeutet der Spruch, dass einem das Trinken eines Gläschen Alkohols von niemandem verboten werden kann.

"Ein Gläschen in Ehren kann niemand verweigern" hat m.E. zwei Interpretationen: (1) Dass man das angebotene Gläschen nicht zurückweisen soll. (2) Dass der Gastgeber gehalten ist, seinem Gast ein Gläschen anzubieten.

Answer (score 2):

Ich finde die vorhanden Antworten unbefriedigend, weil ich die Wörter in ihrer Hauptbedeutung als ziemlich unterschiedlich empfinde, auch wenn sie sich im Grenzfall annähern können.

DWDS sagt zu [verwehren](https://www.dwds.de/wb/verwehren):

> jmdn. an etw. hindern, jmdm. etw. nicht erlauben

Für mich heißt das, dass der Verwehrende aktiv wird und in das Geschehen eingreift.
Das Sprichwort bedeutet, dass ich mich von niemandem daran hindern lasse, einem Glas zuzusprechen.

*Verweigern* kann man dort zwar auch formulieren, die Bedeutung verschiebt sich dann aber in die Richtung, dass wohl kaum jemand das eingeschenkte Glas zurückweisen wird.

[Verweigern](https://www.dwds.de/wb/verweigern) wird bei DWDS definiert als:

> etw. ablehnen, abschlagen

Der Verweigernde macht also weitgehend nichts (vielleicht abgesehen vom Kopfschütteln), beispielsweise der Chef bei der Frage nach einer Gehaltserhöhung, der Befragte bei der Vernehmung, der die Aussage verweigert.